# Backbonejs is calling collection's fetch method in another function good idea? If not what should i use?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to implement endless scrolling with Backbonejs. My view initializes a collection and calls fetch fetch function.

My view

```
var app = app || {};

app.PostListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#posts',
    initialize: function(  ) {
        this.collection = new app.PostList();
        this.collection.on("sync", this.render, this);
        this.collection.fetch();
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
       /*render posts*/ 
    }
});
```

In my page I added the following code. It checks if the the user at the bottom of the page. If yes then it checks if the view is initialized. If yes then call that view fetch function of the view's collection object.

```
var app = app || {};

$(function() {
    var post_view;
    $(window).scroll(function() {

      if(($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == getDocHeight()) && busy==0) {
        if(!post_view){
          post_view = new app.PostListView();
        } else {
          post_view.collection.fetch();                  
        }
      }
   });
});
```

So far this code is working. I am not sure if this is the right approach or not?

Comment: IMHO better to keep window scroll listener inside view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a bad option; it works, and Backbone is making that `collection` available for you. But there's a couple of other options to consider:

- Move that `collection.fetch` into a method `getMoreItems()` inside your `PostListView`, and call it within your `else` block. That way you're encapsulating your logic inside the view. Your app is more modular that way, and you can make your scrolling smarter without updating the rest of your app.
- Move the scroll listener inside your `PostListView`. I'd probably put this within your `PostListView`'s `initialize` function. Again, this reduces dependencies between the various parts of your app - you don't have to remember "Whenever I create a `PostListView`, I must remember to update it on scroll." By setting that event listener within the `PostListView` itself, all you have to do is create it. Backbone's general philosophy is to have small, independent components that manage their own state; moving the event listener inside would fit with that.

Comment: If the scroll listener goes into `PostListView` then you'll need stop listening for scrolling in the `PostListView`'s `remove` and you'll have to make sure to call `remove`. But yeah, it does belong in the view.

Comment: Thanks @alex. I agree with both of the options. I decided to put the scroll listener in view's initialize function. But I want to use _.throttle for the scroll. But i could not figure out how. see here [link](http://pastebin.com/JhYbAy9D). I am wondering should i open another question?